# how to add dependencies when running the Java compiler programmatically

Tags: java, compiler-errors, dynamic-compilation

Hi I am trying to compile a java code(which contains classes from third party jars i.e; dependencies) dynamically and execute the same but its not working for me.

Ex : If i want to execute a simple java code (System.out.println) it works fine but if i add any third party jar files (ex: selenium). It throws error that symbol not found.

```
 import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileWriter;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.Writer;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.net.URLClassLoader;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;
    import javax.tools.Diagnostic;
    import javax.tools.DiagnosticCollector;
    import javax.tools.JavaCompiler;
    import javax.tools.JavaFileObject;
    import javax.tools.StandardJavaFileManager;
    import javax.tools.ToolProvider;

    public class InlineCompiler {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(64);
            sb.append("package testcompile;\n");
      sb.append("import org.sikuli.script.*;\n");
            sb.append("public class HelloWorld implements inlinecompiler.InlineCompiler.DoStuff {\n");
            sb.append("    public void doStuff() {\n");
 sb.append("Screen s = new Screen();\n");
            sb.append("        System.out.println(\"Hello world\");\n");
            sb.append("    }\n");
            sb.append("}\n");

            File helloWorldJava = new File("testcompile/HelloWorld.java");
            if (helloWorldJava.getParentFile().exists() || helloWorldJava.getParentFile().mkdirs()) {

                try {
                    Writer writer = null;
                    try {
                        writer = new FileWriter(helloWorldJava);
                        writer.write(sb.toString());
                        writer.flush();
                    } finally {
                        try {
                            writer.close();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                    }

                    /** Compilation Requirements *********************************************************************************************/
                    DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject>();
                    JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
                    StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(diagnostics, null, null);

                    // This sets up the class path that the compiler will use.
                    // I've added the .jar file that contains the DoStuff interface within in it...
                    List<String> optionList = new ArrayList<String>();
                    optionList.add("-classpath");
                    optionList.add(System.getProperty("java.class.path") + ";sikuli.jar");

                    Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnit
                            = fileManager.getJavaFileObjectsFromFiles(Arrays.asList(helloWorldJava));
                    JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(
                        null, 
                        fileManager, 
                        diagnostics, 
                        optionList, 
                        null, 
                        compilationUnit);
                    /********************************************************************************************* Compilation Requirements **/
                    if (task.call()) {
                        /** Load and execute *************************************************************************************************/
                        System.out.println("Yipe");
                        // Create a new custom class loader, pointing to the directory that contains the compiled
                        // classes, this should point to the top of the package structure!
                        URLClassLoader classLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{new File("./").toURI().toURL()});
                        // Load the class from the classloader by name....
                        Class<?> loadedClass = classLoader.loadClass("testcompile.HelloWorld");
                        // Create a new instance...
                        Object obj = loadedClass.newInstance();
                        // Santity check
                        if (obj instanceof DoStuff) {
                            // Cast to the DoStuff interface
                            DoStuff stuffToDo = (DoStuff)obj;
                            // Run it baby
                            stuffToDo.doStuff();
                        }
                        /************************************************************************************************* Load and execute **/
                    } else {
                        for (Diagnostic<? extends JavaFileObject> diagnostic : diagnostics.getDiagnostics()) {
                            System.out.format("Error on line %d in %s%n",
                                    diagnostic.getLineNumber(),
                                    diagnostic.getSource().toUri());
                        }
                    }
                    fileManager.close();
                } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException exp) {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        public static interface DoStuff {

            public void doStuff();
        }

    }
```

the code should run but it may through error symbol not found.

Comment: Nope.  Not a dup of that Question.  This one is really about how to add dependencies when running the Java compiler programatically.

Comment: Yes you are correct. I may have put the questions incorrectly. Can you suggest any way to add dependencies when running the Java compiler programatically and executing the code.

Answer (score -2):

First of all, I suggest that when printing the diagnostics, add the message.
Change the part that prints the error message to this:

```java
System.out.format("Error %s on line %d in %s%n",
    diagnostic.getMessage(null), // ⇐ Message, very useful
    diagnostic.getLineNumber(),
    diagnostic.getSource().toUri());
```

This will help with understanding *what* the compiler thought went wrong.

On Linux or Mac OS, we now see a problem: Even with a `sikuli.jar` containig a `Screen.class` in the right place, that class `Screen` is not found. Why? Beause Java isn't looking for a `sikuli.jar` file. Why? Because the wrong path concatenation character is used. The path concatenation character is `;` on Windows and `:` on POSIX-y systems. Instead of hard-coding `;`, we should use `System.getProperty("path.separator")`.

I could now see 3 compiler errors (and one message that says "Error" but is actually a warning):

- cannot find symbol "class DoStuff"
- cannot find symbol "class Screen" (twice)

So, change the line that builds the classpath entry in the `optionList` to this:

```java
optionList.add(System.getProperty("java.class.path") + System.getProperty("path.separator") + "sikuli.jar");
```

After this change, the code works.

Here's the directory structure that I used:

```
playground/ ⇐ current working directory
+- inlinecompiler/
|  +- Compiler.java
+- sikuli.jar ⇐ contains org/sikuli/script/Screen.class
```

And the commands:

```bash
javac inlinecompiler/Compiler.java
java -cp .:sikuli.jar inlinecompiler.Compiler
```

Which means if it doesn't work, also check your directory structure.

Last but not least, `java.lang.Compiler` is deprecated and scheduled for removal. You might want to switch to `javax.tools.JavaCompiler`. You can obtain an instance using:

```java
JavaCompiler compiler = ServiceLoader.load(JavaCompiler.class).iterator().next();
```